# Program doesn't work if fed with a large amount of data

Tags: python-3.x

#This program takes in a text file and whatever the ser types in ; it searches for the specific word or phrase and then print out in which line this word or phrase is located .
If i feed it a text file with 20 lines , it produces normal results
As soon as i give it a 3000 worded document it produces error
Can anyone explain this

```
while True:
    search = str(input("==>"))

    line_number = 1

    fslope = open("searching_in_a_textfile")

    for line in fslope:
        if search.lower() in line:
            print("tHE LINE NUMBER IS ", line_number)
            print("THE LINE SAYS : " + line)
            line_number = line_number + 1
            continue

        if search.upper() in line:
            print("tHE LINE NUMBER IS ", line_number)
            print("THE LINE SAYS : " + line)
            line_number = line_number + 1
            continue

        if search.title() in line:
            print("tHE LINE NUMBER IS ", line_number)
            print("THE LINE SAYS : " + line)
            line_number = line_number + 1
            continue

        else:
            line_number = line_number + 1
            continue

    print("END OF PRIOCESS")
```

Comment: btw                     while True: search = str(input("==>"))         is a part of the program

Comment: What is the error? Edit your post to include the full error and traceback

Comment: Your else statement is only occuring if the 3rd if statement condition is not met. Update your second and third if statement to elif.

Answer (score 0):

First lets make it simple: (this code is almost the same as yours)

```py
lines = []
with open('searching_in_a_textfile') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

while True:
    search = input('==>')
    if not search:
        break
    for line_number, line in enumerate(lines, 1):
        if search.lower() in line.lower():
            print('tHE LINE NUMBER IS ', line_number, '\nTHE LINE SAYS :', line)

    print("END OF PRIOCESS")
```

Now when the input is `''` (empty string / no input) the process will stop.
if you can add your error it could be very helpful.